# Notifying salesforce changes to external rest api services

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, rest

Can someone help me with the design to follow to notify salesforce changes to an external rest api?

If I create a new account in salesforce it should trigger a notification to an external system through that external system's rest api

What is the best way to do this? Should I use triggers, batch or any other methods?

Comment: If its a service thats forever changin, it makes sense to implement it in middleware than in Salesforce.

Comment: May be i will elaborate ,need to inform external system when an account is created in salesforce ,through rest api.

Comment: Can you edit question and add more details. its more ambiguous.  You want whenever a new account is created, same should be updated in External System?

Comment: Do you want it to be realtime/instantaneous or it can wait for sometime?

Comment: Real time is the requirement....

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty normal use case,present since ages. Lets see what solution Salesforce has and how it suits different architecture.

1. ***Outbound Messages*** : One of the earliest solution to integration, These are soap messsages sent to external endpoint with the latest record created/updated data.

**Advantages** :
Unlimited outbound messages can be posted, Can be done with clicks and not code, Realtime

**Disadvantages** : SOAP Based(Kinda outdated), Not much tracking functionality

2. ***Future/Queueable*** : We can fire future/queueable from Apex Trigger. They run asynchronously after the current running transaction has committed into the database.

**Advantages** : Can use Rest , Supports complex XML/JSON Structure. Queueable can be tracked, Runs as a new transaction, gets new set of limit

**Disadvantages** : Only 250,000 a day. NO SLA. I have seen future/queueable running 3 hours after firing, Bulk implementation is quite complex.

3. ***Batches / Scheduler*** : Batches are used for bulk processing. Schduler allows you to run jobs at given time. So you can combine both to run Scheduled Batches every 15 mins . 
   This is similar to number 2. But this approch will consume less Apex Async Jobs

**Advantages** : Bulkified, Supports  complex XML/JSON Structure, would consume less ApexAsyncJobs

**Disadvantages** : No SLA, If you add too many batches it goes in FLEX queue.

4. ***Platform Events / Change Data Capture*** : This is the latest offering by Salesforce. This involves posting a message in Message Bus which an external system is listening. This is super near realtime and the future.

**Advantages**: Fast reliable, Can replay past events, Support complex JSON/XML by addding in text area fiel
**Disadvantages** : External System would have to implement COMET D listening interface to get notification of newly created/updated records

5. ***Using External ETL/ESB Tools*** : An ETL tool will periodically poll SF for any Created/Updated records and then it can send it to external Endpoint. Eg(Mulesoft)

**Advantages** : No change in SF, Super Flexible

**Disadvantages** : Need expertise in ETL/ESB

Comment: For #2, I'd suggest an additional disadvantage is that implementation that handles bulk data loads is significantly more complex than many developers think, and naive implementations are really easy to break.

Comment: @DavidReed So true. And things get funny if there are recursive updates and you don't wanna get stuck in a recursive loop, given that there is no Limit on Queuable  chaining.